# Conditional Logic and Casting in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm creating a script that imports 2 columns of CSV data, sorts by one column cast as type int, and shows only the values between 0 and 10,000.  I've been able to get up to the sorting part, and I am able to show only greater than 0.  When I try to add "-and -lt 10000" various ways, I am unable to get any useful data.  One attempt gave me the data as if it were string again, though.

This only gives me > 0 but sorts as type int.  Half way there!:

`PS C:\> $_ = Import-Csv .\vc2.csv | Select -Property User_Name, Minutes; $_ | Sort {[int] $_.Minutes} | Where {($_.Minutes -gt 0)}`

This gives me 10000 > x > 0 but sorts as string:

`PS C:\> $_ = Import-Csv .\vc.csv | Select -Property User_Name, Minutes; $_ | Sort {[int] $_.Minutes} | Where {($_.Minutes -gt 0) -and ($_.Minutes -lt 10)}`

Here and here are where I tried recasting as int and it gave me many errors:

`PS C:\> $_ = Import-Csv .\vc.csv | Select -Property User_Name, Minutes; $_ | Sort {[int] $_.Minutes} | Where {[int]{($_.Minutes -gt 0) -and ($_.Minutes -lt 10000)}}`

`PS C:\> $_ = Import-Csv .\vc.csv | Select -Property User_Name, Minutes; $_ | Sort {[int] $_.Minutes} | Where { ({[int]$_.Minutes} -gt 0) -and ({[int]$_.Minutes} -lt 10000) }`

Error: Cannot convert the "($*.Minutes -gt 0) -and ($*.Minutes -lt 10000)" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock" to type "System.Int32".

What is the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell usually coerces arguments of binary operators to the type of the *left* operand. This means when doing `$_.Minutes -gt 10` the `10` gets converted to a string, because the fields in a parsed CSV are always strings. You can either switch the operands around: `10 -lt $_.Minutes` or add a cast: `[int]$_.Minutes -gt 10` or `+$_.Minutes -gt 10`.

Usually, when dealing with CSVs that contain non-string data that I want to use as such, I tend to just add a post-processing step, e.g.:

```
Import-Csv ... | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Minutes = [int]$_.Minutes
  $_.Date = [datetime]$_.Date
  ...
}
```

Afterwards the data is much nicer to handle, without excessive casts and conversions.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the heads up about the left operand.  I got it to work by switching them just like you said.  Now I have: `Import-Csv .\vc2.csv | Select -Property User_Name, Minutes | Sort -Property {[int] $_.Minutes} -Descending | Where {((9999 -gt $_.Minutes) -and (0 -lt $_.Minutes))}`  The strange thing is that the -lt was working fine beforehand.  It was just the -gt doing that as far as I can tell.

Comment: This would depend a bit on the data. E.g. most numeric strings would be larger than the number 0, for example, and numeric strings less than 9999 would also be smaller than the number 9999.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of the { and } brackets in the Where statement. Those are being interpreted as script blocks.

```
Where { ({[int]$_.Minutes} -gt 0) -and ({[int]$_.Minutes} -lt 10000) }
```

Try using ( and ) or excluding them altogether.

```
Where { (([int]$_.Minutes) -gt 0) -and (([int]$_.Minutes) -lt 10000) }
```

The way you're assigning values to $_ is also weird.

Comment: When I take off the brackets, but leave the -and nothing will print.  Not even an error.  I tried replacing with parenthesis and isolating it, but it just won't print without them.  If I take off the -and it will print, but the -gt won't work either way.  -lt works fine, though.

This is what I have at the moment:

`PS C:\> Import-Csv .\vc2.csv | Select -Property User_Name, Minutes | Sort -Property {[int] $_.Minutes} -Descending | Where {(($_.Minutes-lt 9999) -and ($_.Minutes -gt 0))}`

Comment: I got it figured out now.  I forgot to put a `;$_` anywhere at the end.

Answer (score 0):

$_ represents the current value in the pipeline.

```
$list = @(1,2,3)
$list | foreach { $_ }
1
2
3
```

by assigning "$_" a value, you are losing that value as soon as you place it in the pipeline.

try something like:
    $mycsv = import-csv .\vc.csv; $mycsv | select ...etc

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I'm starting to get the hang of things.